# Render WPF application to get output in .jpg / .png

Tags: wpf, expression-blend-4

I need to render a .obj imported from AutoDesk 3DS max to get an output in jpg or png file. How do I do it? I am using Expression blend 4 and WPF Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SharpGL](http://sharpgl.codeplex.com/), a C# library which makes it super easy to use OpenGL in your C# applications. It does include support for directly loading .obj files.

**Double Edit**: I've replaced my code samples with an implementation using them. I have ran the following code, and it does work, it loads up a .obj and renders it on screen with no problems

XAML ..Make sure you add

```
xmlns:sharpGL="clr-namespace:SharpGL.WPF;assembly=SharpGL.WPF"
```

to the window properties

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Add Item" Click="Add_Click" />
        <Button Content="Take Screen Shot" Click="ScreenShot_Click" />
    </StackPanel>

    <sharpGL:OpenGLControl Grid.Row="1" Name="myOpenGLControl"
        OpenGLDraw="OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw" OpenGLInitialized="OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized"
        RenderContextType="FBO" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind

**Note**: I haven't actually implemented the saving of the graphics, but at this point you can render on screen a preview of the model.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    float rotation_angle = 0f;
    float rotation_x = 0f;
    float rotation_y = 0f;
    float rotation_z = 0f;

    private List<Polygon> _polygons = new List<Polygon>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myOpenGLControl.OpenGL.Enable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, SharpGL.SceneGraph.OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

        // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Move Left And Into The Screen
        gl.LoadIdentity();
        gl.Translate(0.0f, -1.0f, -10.0f);

        gl.Rotate(rotation_angle, rotation_x, rotation_y, rotation_z);

        foreach (Polygon polygon in _polygons)
        {
            polygon.PushObjectSpace(gl);
            polygon.Render(gl, SharpGL.SceneGraph.Core.RenderMode.Render);
            polygon.PopObjectSpace(gl);
        }

        rotation_angle += 3;
        rotation_x = 0;
        rotation_y = 20;
        rotation_z = -5;
    }

    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized(object sender, SharpGL.SceneGraph.OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

        gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        float[] global_ambient = new float[] { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
        float[] light0pos = new float[] { 0.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f };
        float[] light0ambient = new float[] { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
        float[] light0diffuse = new float[] { 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f };
        float[] light0specular = new float[] { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };

        float[] lmodel_ambient = new float[] { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
        gl.LightModel(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, lmodel_ambient);

        gl.LightModel(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, global_ambient);
        gl.Light(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT0, OpenGL.GL_POSITION, light0pos);
        gl.Light(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT0, OpenGL.GL_AMBIENT, light0ambient);
        gl.Light(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT0, OpenGL.GL_DIFFUSE, light0diffuse);
        gl.Light(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT0, OpenGL.GL_SPECULAR, light0specular);
        gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_LIGHT0);

        gl.ShadeModel(OpenGL.GL_SMOOTH);
    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Polygon> polygons = LoadScene("ducky.obj");
        polygons.ScaleMaxExtentTo(10);
        _polygons.AddRange(polygons);
    }

    private void ScreenShot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here you can use either of the below methods to get the raw pixel data
        //which needs to be manually formatted for the file type of your choice.
        //myOpenGLControl.OpenGL.ReadBuffer();
        //myOpenGLControl.OpenGL.ReadPixels();
    }

    private List<Polygon> LoadScene(string filePath)
    {
        List<Polygon> polygons = new List<Polygon>();
        Scene scene = SerializationEngine.Instance.LoadScene(filePath);
        if (scene != null)
        {
            polygons.AddRange(scene.SceneContainer.Traverse<Polygon>());
        }

        return polygons;
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>Scales the polygons to not excede the maximum size in OpenGL Units.</summary>
    public static void ScaleMaxExtentTo(this List<Polygon> polygons, float maxSize)
    {
        foreach (var polygon in polygons) { polygon.ScaleMaxExtentTo(maxSize); }
    }

    /// <summary>Scales the polygon to not excede the maximum size in OpenGL Units.</summary>
    public static void ScaleMaxExtentTo(this Polygon polygon, float maxSize)
    {
        float[] extent = new float[3];
        polygon.BoundingVolume.GetBoundDimensions(out extent[0], out extent[1], out extent[2]);
        float maxExtent = extent.Max();
        float scaleFactor = maxExtent > maxSize ? maxSize / maxExtent : 1;
        polygon.Transformation.ScaleX = scaleFactor;
        polygon.Transformation.ScaleY = scaleFactor;
        polygon.Transformation.ScaleZ = scaleFactor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Found some discussion on the topic here regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421600/3ds-max-object-to-opengl

Comment: I am not sure how this works. i couldn't get it to work. I am a rookie and just started with WPF so please help

Comment: @user2575033 What exactly could you not get to work... could you explain what you tried to do?

Comment: Thank you so much i appeeciate your help. I am just using viewport in Expression blend 4 and adding texture to .obj and .mtl file from 3DS max. so Open GL is not in for me. i just need to render the content displayed in design view of blend 4 in .png or .jpeg format

Comment: @user2575033 Okay, so you just need to take a screenshot of the viewport? If not... you could use OpenGL, you will just have to send over the viewports angles/coordinates, and you can render it in OpenGL... but if it is just a screenshot you need, that would be much simpler.

Comment: yes i need only screenshot of viewport but only way to do it that i know of is printscreen which is not what i want to do.